# where to get list of all bindable properties for angular http elements?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

MDN says: 
If you want default content for your , you enter it between the opening and closing tags.  **does not support the value attribute**.

but in angular property binding we can bind to value.

```
<textarea rows="10" [value]="'test'" ></textarea>
```

is there any online repository where we can find all the properties with regard to angular.??

Answer (score 0):

I found the article ["HTML Attributes vs DOM Properties and Angular 2 Data Binding"](https://medium.com/@vaqifagayev/html-attributes-vs-dom-properties-and-angular-2-data-binding-9e6e5a09c69d) useful, especially the following sections:

> DOM is basically collection of objects (window,html,body, head and etc) which allows us to manipulate it. It means that HTML elements are contained in the DOM as objects.HTML elements have attributes which initilizes DOM properties. Once initilization process is done attributes job is done.

```
<input type=”text” value=”5">
```

> Given input element has type and value attributes. When HTML element is created its properties which have similar names to attributes (but not same thing) is created, too. After initilization given input element have properties such as type and value.

[Angular property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) acts on the elements/objects contained in the DOM. You can find a list of properties of all element **interfaces** at [MDN Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) documentation. Most of the one's you're interested in, have a name that starts with 'HTML'.

The [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) interface for example corresponds to the `<textarea>` element. You can use all its properties and the properties of its parent interfaces for Angular property binding as long as they're not read only.